# Django allauth module throw error at login?

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

This is happen at login submit form, the problem is that I do not know how to debug it

> AttributeError at /users/login/ 'NoneType' object has no attribute
>   'is_active'
>
> Exception
>   Location: C:\projects\Django-project\lib\site-packages\allauth\account\utils.py
>   in perform_login, line 132

**project/users/forms.py:**

```
from django import forms
from allauth.account.forms import LoginForm, SignupForm
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

class LoginForm(LoginForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['login'].widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'text', 'class': 'input-text'})
        self.fields['login'].label = _('Username')
        self.fields['password'].widget = forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'input-text'})
        self.fields['remember'].label = _('Remember me')

    def clean(self):

        error_dict = {}

        login_data = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        if len(login_data) < 3:
            error_dict['login'] = forms.ValidationError('Добави още символи2!')


        password_data = self.cleaned_data.get('login')
        if len(password_data) < 3:
            error_dict['password'] = forms.ValidationError('Добави още символи2!')

        if error_dict:
            raise forms.ValidationError(error_dict)
        else:
            return True



class SignupForm(SignupForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].widget = forms.TextInput()

    def clean(self):
        error_dict = {}
        username_data = self.cleaned_data.get('username')

        if len(username_data) < 3:
            error_dict['username'] = forms.ValidationError('тест по-малко от 2')

        if error_dict:
            raise forms.ValidationError(error_dict)
        else:
            return True
```

**project/users/views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views import generic
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

# Create your views here.

    def redirect_to_user_profile(request):
        url = f'/users/profile/{request.user.id}'
        return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to=url)


    class UserProfileView(generic.DetailView):
        model = User
        template_name = 'user_profile.html'
```

I can provide much more information (code) if need it.

**P.S:** The problem comes from `project/users/forms.py:` if I delete whole `def clean(self):` it works fine.

Comment: A form's `clean()` method needs to return the cleaned data. When subclassing a form, the first thing you should do is call `cleaned_data = super().clean()` and at the end `return cleaned_data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When overriding a form's `clean()` method, you need to return the cleaned data. [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/#validating-fields-with-clean) the documentation of how it works with an example:

- Always first call `cleaned_data = super().clean()` to get an instance of `cleaned_data`.
- Always finish by `return cleaned_data`, because that's what gets assigned to `Form.cleaned_data`. So don't `return True`!

Note that since you're cleaning individual fields, you're better off overriding the individual field cleaning methods `clean_<field>`, e.g.:

```
def clean_login(self):
    login_data = self.cleaned_data['login']
    if len(login_data) < 3:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Добави още символи2!')
    return login_data
```